# Correct interface of a business logic class

Tags: c#, oop

In a program with separated UI from business logic; I have a Garage, containing a list of Vehicle(licensePlate, coniditionOfVehicle)

I want to allow users of Garage to receive a list of all the licensePlates at a specific given conditionOfVehicle.

1. what should be the return type of the method? IList of string (exactly what the requirement states) vs IList of Vehicle (allowing for the client to see more properties of the car, thereby improving extensibility)
2. are we even allowed to return a Vehicle? this would allow the user to change things we might not want him to. (assume that the client has access to "Vehicle", as it is using a Builder to receive a Vehicle, and then calls the Garage.AddVehicle(vehicle) to add it to the garage)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a [YAGNI (You Arent Gonna Need It)](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt) principle which states:

> Always implement things when you actually need them, never when you
>   just foresee that you need them.

If requirement says 'users need list of licensePlates' then simply return what users need without trying to foresee what they might need. Otherwise you are wasting time on forecasting, you are adding possible problems (changing of vehicles by user), you are making your code unexpected both for users (they expect licensePlates) and for maintainers (they don't know where new requirement come from), and worst thing - new 'feature' might be not used by users.

Another principle which you are trying to violate by returning whole vehicle instance is [KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid)](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?KeepItSimple):

> If you have a choice between a simple solution and a complex one, then
>   opting for complexity would be stupid.

Returning list of strings is more simple solution, which satisfies requirements. There is no need to add needless complexity to your system.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree on that point, but would like to know what would you do if after you have implemented it this way, the client came to you and said that he also needs to know the color of the associated cars (because he wants to make a graph of condition of cars vs their colors). would you now make a new type consiting of simply (LicensePlate, Color) or would you return Vehicle?

Comment: @Jackl56 that depends. Usually I try to avoid adding new data types to system. But if you are transferring data over network (DTO), or its a specific view model, then usually creating new data type will be better solution. So here you should chose between increasing complexity of system by adding new types and transferring additional data which not required by user.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think it's really a matter of preference. assuming I am not transferring data over the network, I am looking for a better way of doing it or at least some guidelines to decide between the two, Because it doesn't make sense to me to create a new class for every method that wants to return a different set of values

Comment: @Jackl56 I neither said that is matter of preference, nor that you should do it only for transferring data over network (view models are also good example). You should make decisions based on your project needs, as with selecting between performance and readability.